# SLIC superpixel labels opencv

Tags: android, opencv, superpixels

After applying `SLIC superpixel` on an input image, I need to get the max value of the labels from the Red, Blue and Green channel.

I wrote this code, First I applied the `SLIC Superpixel` and then I used the split command to get the 3 channels. Then i used the `Core.minMaxLoc` command.

My question is, the Max returned from `Core.minMaxLoc` is the Max of pixels or the labels? Because I need to extract the maximum value from the labels not the pixel.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "3:qinQctivity";
Button button;
ImageView imageView,imageView_red,imageView_blue,imageView_green;
TextView textView,mean_text;
Double Max_Red,Max_Green,Max_Blue;

Mat newImage,newMat,mask,labels,BGR_RGB,Blue,Green,Red;
ArrayList<Mat> RGB = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView_red = findViewById(R.id.image_red);
    imageView_blue = findViewById(R.id.image_blue);
    imageView_green = findViewById(R.id.image_green);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mean_text = findViewById(R.id.textView2);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
                OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_4_0, getApplicationContext(), baseLoaderCallback);
            } else {

                baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    });

}
BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        super.onManagerConnected(status);
        if (status == LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS) {
            try {
                newImage = new Mat();
                newMat = new Mat();
                labels = new Mat();
                BGR_RGB = new Mat();


                BGR_RGB = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.retinalimage, CvType.CV_32FC3);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(BGR_RGB,newImage,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGB);

                SuperpixelSLIC x = Ximgproc.createSuperpixelSLIC(newImage, Ximgproc.SLIC, 50, (float) 0.001);
                x.iterate(5);
                if (true){
                    x.enforceLabelConnectivity(20);
                }

                mask = new Mat();
                x.getLabelContourMask(mask, true);
                newImage.setTo(new Scalar(0, 0, 255), mask);

                showImage(newImage);
                labels = new Mat();
                x.getLabels(labels);

                //count the number of the superpixel segmented regions
                int a = x.getNumberOfSuperpixels();

                // working on the Red, Blue and green channel
                Core.split(newImage,RGB);
                Red = RGB.get(0);
                Green = RGB.get(1);
                Blue = RGB.get(2);

                Max_Red = Core.minMaxLoc(Red).maxVal;
                Max_Green = Core.minMaxLoc(Green).maxVal;
                Max_Blue = Core.minMaxLoc(Blue).maxVal;


                Scalar P = Core.mean(newImage);
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(P));
                mean_text.setText(String.valueOf(P));
                showImage(newImage);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        }

    }

} ;
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by _max of pixels or labels_. Your code will return the maximum value in the label that you use (Red, Green or Blue).

Comment: for exemple if i apply Core.meanStdDev(Red, mean, std); the value in return it's going to be the mean of the image pixels or the mean of the superpixel region segmented by the SLIC ?!

Comment: It will obviously get the mean of image pixels and not the superpixel since the you call the function Core.meanStdDev on the channel and not on the superpixel label.

Comment: what I have to do to get the mean of the superpixel, by the way i got that channel by applying split on the segmented image [Red channel](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O36mzv-5G4Tw8FIiq144u-KxtZ3OF6u8/)

Comment: here the Red channel after applying the Split on the segmented image : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O36mzv-5G4Tw8FIiq144u-KxtZ3OF6u8

Comment: Well, I'd suggest reading the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/da9/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1SuperpixelSLIC.html#aca4e1b5813a6c16635700c85b9f13c23). You have to get boundaries of the labels where the superpixels are found. Then, you'd have to find the max of these boundaries in your image (or channel). If you can upload an example image, I'd add the working version in Python

Comment: the doc can't answer my question because i need to extract the Max intensity value from the 3 channels (Red,Blue,Green) of the lebels ( called also cluster or superpixel) returned by the SILC.